# Min heap of objects based on property in object

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I am new to C++ and I am trying to use the STL priority queue to make a min heap of objects based of off the distance property in the object.  I am not fully sure what I need to do but I've looked around and I that my priority queue would look something like this:

```
std::priority_queue<Class, std::vector<Class>, object.distance> pq;
```

What I am not fully sure about is how I go about overloading the comparison operator first to change the heap to a min heap and second to compare my objects based off of a property.  Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016921/comparator-for-min-heap-in-c help?

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is the heap opperations that take the comparators, *not* your contianer.
Presuming that your function has this prototype: `static bool object::distance( Class, Class );`
Then you can use the [std::make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) function, like this `std::make_heap( pq.begin(), pq.end(), object::distance )`

It's probably worth noting that a std::priority_queue doesn't have a begin or end method and doesn't provide the RandomAcessIterators that you need for the STL's heap functions. The fact that you are trying to make a heap out of your queue indicates that you are missusing the container. A priority_queue already has it's own ordering. If you want to use a heap you can just use a vector, like this: `std::vector< Class > pq;`